# Show $(\vec x\cdot\nabla)\vec F=t \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$ where $\vec F(\vec x,t)=\vec B(t \vec x)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I keep missing the factor of $t$. My working:
$$(\vec x\cdot\nabla)\vec F=(x_i \vec e_i\cdot\vec e_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j})F_k\vec e_k=x_j\frac{\partial F_k}{\partial x_j}\vec e_k$$
and
$$\frac{\partial\vec F}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec B(t\vec x)=(\vec x\cdot\nabla B_i(t\vec x))\vec e_i=(x_j\vec e_j\cdot\frac{\partial B_i(t\vec x)}{\partial x_k}\vec e_k)\vec e_i=x_k\frac{\partial B_i(t\vec x)}{\partial x_k}\vec e_i=x_k\frac{F_i}{x_k}\vec e_i$$
which would seem to suggest that the two lines are equal, when there should be a factor of $t$ between them.

I'm not sure I have differentiated correctly on the second line, but I can't see a better way.

What is the correct way to partial differentiate a time dependent vector field with respect to time?

Answer (score 1):

I will work the problem where $F$ and $B$ are scalars and we have just the one position coordinate $x$. I leave it to you to generalize to the situation where $F$ and $B$ are time-dependent vector fields in three dimensions.

I think the best way to work such problems is the chain rule. Let $g(x,t) = tx$. Then $F = B \circ g$, so $$DF(x,t) = DB(g(x,t)) \cdot Dg(x,t) = DB(xt) \cdot Dg(x,t)$$ We have
$$
Dg (x,t) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
t & x
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Of course
$$
DB(xt) = B'(xt)
$$
So
$$
DF(x,t) = \begin{bmatrix} tB'(xt) & xB'(xt)\end{bmatrix}
$$
In particular, we see that
$$
t \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(x,t) = t \left(x B'(xt) \right) = tx B'(xt)
$$
We also find
$$
(x \cdot \nabla) F (x,t) = x \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = x  (t B'(xt)) = tx B'(xt)
$$
Therefore, we conclude
$$
(x \cdot \nabla) F = t \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What is $D$ here?

Comment: Notation I'm using for the derivative. See [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~nikhil/courses/121a/chain.pdf). This might be a new concept for you, but if you know partial derivatives and how to multiply matrices, there's nothing here that's computationally beyond your reach.

Comment: This seems like a nice way of solving the problem, but I don't think it is intended for my course. Is there a way of solving this using summation convention (as I unsuccessfully did in the body of the question)?